# Import a function in a React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, import

Having the following import done into a test file:

[image]

This works fine, but the problem appears when I want to import it into another file, here it is:

[image]

What is wrong with this import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're in the components directory already, going up 3 levels takes you to /libs so you don't need the /libs in your path just
../../../shared
By the way - screenshots not so good text better.